# Why is the dark mode with media query not working?

Tags: html, css

I have example like this, why is the button background changing to black while `@media` queries are not reacting to color-scheme property?

```css
html {
  color-scheme: dark;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background: grey;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  body {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Color</button>
<p>testtext</p>
```

Comment: are you sure? here on Firefox it correctly shows the button hover always as `dark`; and the body background as `gray` when my settings have `dark` color scheme, and `yellow` otherwise when settings have the `light` color scheme. Chrome doesn't have built in dark and light color schemes (afaik) but lets you pick a color scheme from a broader pool

Comment: but seems I'm not able to set
html {
     color-scheme: dark;
}
that's not working bouth firefox and chrome and @media  quarries are not reacting for my html {
     color-scheme: dark;
} settings
even using the last versions

Comment: Not working? It's grey right? Please add more details.

Comment: [color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme) _"Common choices for operating system color schemes are "light" and "dark", or "day mode" and "night mode". When a user selects one of these color schemes, the operating system makes adjustments to the user interface. ***This includes form controls, scrollbars***, and the used values of CSS system colors."_ ...I cited the mdn page because at this point I'm not sure if you just have wrong expectations. What did you expect from `html{color-scheme: dark;}`? please don't limit the answer to _"it's not working"_